# Manipulating Entity Framework entities automatically to add extra information

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, dbcontext

I am looking to run some code when any entity is created.  Been looking in the DbContext for something to override but having some difficulty finding anything useful.

To explain a bit more... I have a couple of models and when I use one of these models to return data in an entity I wish to be able to do something with the entity before it is returned to the calling method.  I want to define this code once per model at the most and I want it to happen for all entities.

Any EF experts out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DbContext` doesn't offer such mechanism but you can use this:

```
ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
objectContext.ObjectMaterialized += (sender,e) => {
    var yourEntity = e.Entity as YourEntityType;
    if (yourEntity != null) {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

Comment: Where would be the best place to put this code?  In EF5 with ObjectContext, we could hook in via OnContextCreated, but I can't find a suitable equivalent in EF6 with DbContext.